# How to process csv in Batch while retaining null columns

Tags: csv, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

In Windows batch I need to process a CSV with a known number of total columns.  The columns are not guaranteed to be populated and different columns may have null values.  I tried `for /f` but it seems to collapse multiple delimiters into one and I loose the column structure.  This is what I tried so far, given `sample.csv`:

```
a,b,,d,,f
a,,c,,,
a,b,c,d,e,f
,,,d,,f
```

I have a batch script:

```
  @echo off
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /F "tokens=1-6,* delims=," %%A in (sample.csv) do (
    echo A=%%~A
    echo B=%%~B
    echo C=%%~C
    echo D=%%~D
    echo E=%%~E
    echo F=%%~F
    echo.
  )
```

When it gets to columns with repeating delimiters it is collapsing them:

```
A=a
B=b
C=d
D=f
E=
F=

A=a
B=c
C=
D=
E=
F=

A=a
B=b
C=c
D=d
E=e
F=f

A=d
B=f
C=
D=
E=
F=
```

How do I get a reference to each of the columns in the csv, even null columns?

Comment: Do any columns contain "quoted values", especially "quoted values, that contain commas" ?

Comment: My first recommendation is using PowerShell and a PowerShell script for the task because of PowerShell has built-in support for real CSV file processing. My second recommendation is looking on the Stack Overflow search results [\[batch-file\] CSV file empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+CSV+file+empty+values). There can be used also a VBScript processed by the Windows Script Host (`cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`). In fact every other script interpreter is better than the Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` interpreting a batch file to process a CSV file.

Comment: @Mofi  I agree batch is not ideal for this, but due to security policy on the machine I’m using it’s all that I have available. Even power shell is restricted.

Comment: @Magoo there are quoted strings but no errant commas.

Comment: I’m thinking I could read each line as a whole and do a string replace on ,, and convert it to ,0, and then feed it into my processor to pick out the fields I want. I can live with zeros instead of null values.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mofi's comment: nearly everything is better than batch for this task.

If you for whatever reason are limited to batch, it is possible with certain restrictions (no quotes on any fields or commas or linefeeds or exclamation marks  within a field):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%z in (sample.csv) do (
  set "line="%%z""
  set "line=!line:,=","!"
  for /f "tokens=1-6,* delims=," %%a in ("!line!") do (
    echo %%~a+%%~b+%%~c+%%~d+%%~e+%%~f+%%~g
  )
)
```